# Python Server Help

Tags: python, windows, http

I have written a small HTTP server and everything is working fine locally, but I am not able to connect to the server from any other computer, including other computers on the network. I'm not sure if it is a server problem, or if I just need to make some adjustments to Windows. I turned the firewall off, so that can't be the probelm.

I am using Python 2.6 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any code sample I can only assume that your server is listening on some private interface like localhost/127.0.0.1 and not something that is connected to the rest of your network.

Comment: DUH! Some things are too simple I guess. Thanks! :)

Comment: I would have guessed at port 80, since that's privileged.

Comment: Then you normally get some error message by the underlying OS that you have to be a privileged user (in the form of that nice black screen :-P) IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

1. Can you connect to the server via your machine's IP instead of localhost? I.e. if your machine is 1.2.3.4 in the network and the server is listening on port 8080, can you see it by opening a browser to `http://1.2.3.4:8080` on the same machine?
2. Can you do (1) from another machine? (just a sanity check...)
3. Do other servers work throughout the network? I.e. if you run a simple FTP server (like Filezilla server) on the machine, can you FTP to it from other machines?
4. Can you ping one machine from another?
5. Do you still have firewalls running? (i.e. default Windows firewall)